# Which version of SAGA is included with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, saga

Is there a way of working out which version of SAGA has been packaged with a particular version of QGIS from qgis.org - without downloading and installing?

The reason I ask is that I am trying to run some training, and I want to ensure that not-particularly-computer-savvy users download an appropriate version. One of the SAGA processing algorithms required for this training was there in QGIS 3.18.1 (SAGA 2.3.2), but the algorithm is missing in 3.20.0 (SAGA 7.8.2). [The algorithm is actually in SAGA 7.8.2, but has been renamed since 2.3.2, and is not built into the SAGA provider in QGIS 3.20.0]

More confusingly, LTR 3.16.8:

1. If you download the MSI, has SAGA 7.8.2
2. If you download the EXE ("continued with dependencies from old OSGeo4W") you get SAGA 2.3.2

I'm particularly concerned about MacOS, because being a Windows user, I can't install the DMGs to see what's in there.

Comment: "One of the SAGA processing algorithms", name plz? To sort out if missing algorithm is a bug or a feature. The question is in fact a way to bypass another issue ;)

Comment: @ThomasG77 - the missing algorithm in QGIS is SAGA->Terrain Analysis - Hydrology->Catchment Area (there are others). In SAGA 7.8.2, this appears to have been renamed TIN Tools->Flow Accumulation (Parallel), but this  is missing in QGIS for Windows (LTR 3.16.8 MSI & 3.20.0). The reason I haven't raised this as a bug is that the QGIS team is moving SAGA, and other providers, to plugins (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/43792) and this is targeted for QGIS 3.22.0, so I suspect the issue is effectively already resolved (or if it is an issue, will be a plugin bug, not be a QGIS bug!).

Answer (score 4):

For Mac, I think you can check the deps files listed on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Mac-Packager

e.g. for LTR https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-ltr.deps?raw=true which lists saga 7.3.0

Comment: Thanks @underdark - that's certainly very useful. However, I'm now quite confused by info sent to me by a MacOS user that showed QGIS 3.20 for MacOS, with SAGA v7.3.0, but also SAGA->Terrain Analysis - Hydrology->Catchment Area tool (the algorithm of interest) in the Processing Toolbox. But SAGA 7.3.0 documentation doesn't have a Catchment Area tool - but does have its replacement - TIN Tools->Flow Accumulation (Parallel).

Comment: Hello, @underdark. I had a question: what is the latest SAGA version, which can be installed on Windows 7 32 bit system separately from QGIS. But now I have already found the answer: SAGA 7.9.1. Link  https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%207/SAGA%20-%207.9.1/

Answer (score 3):

To see the dependencies on Windows, you can look at both OSGEO4W setup.ini files (old and new) as the installer, remote or standalone are all based on OSGEO4W, old or new.

Text based, you can search them with term "saga"

- New OSGEO4W installer (also called "OSGeo4W v2") https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/x86_64/setup.ini
- Old OSGEO4W installer https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v2/x86_64/setup.ini

For DMG, you can list files using latest version of 7zip (need version 19+). On Linux, I needed to get a more recent version from https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/7fe6c21efa/#40a6 (binary named `7zz`) as all official version for Linux are based on 7zip 16.02. I've used command line `./7zz l ~/Download/qgis-macos-pr.dmg |grep libsaga_api-` to confirm the version. It can also be useful